# Traffic Motion Recognition

Tags: computer-vision, motion-detection

I'm trying to build a simple traffic motion monitor to estimate average speed of moving vehicles, and I'm looking for guidance on how to do so using an open source package like OpenCV or others that you might recommend for this purpose. Any good resources that are particularly good for this problem?

The setup I'm hoping for is to install a webcam on a high-rise building next to the road in question, and point the camera down onto moving traffic. Camera altitude would be anywhere between 20 ft and 100ft, and the building would be anywhere between 20ft and 500ft away from the road.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: Far, far, far, far too broad a question.

Comment: how is it too broad? (in other words, can you help me narrow it down or better formulate an approach or kickstart me?) are there that many ways to solve the problem? if so, are there not some approaches that are more likely to work better for traffic speed?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you need a way to detect cars so you can get their 2D coordinates in the video frame. You might want to use a tracker to speed up the process and take advantage of the predictable motion of the vehicles.  You, also, need a way to calibrate the camera so you can translate the 2D coordinates in the image to depth information so you can approximate speed.

So as a first step, look at detectors such as deformable parts model DPM, and tracking by detection methods. You'll probably need to port some code from Matlab (and if you do, please make it available :-) ). If that's too slow, maybe do some segmentation of foreground blobs, and track the colour histogram or HOG descriptors using a Particle Filter or a Kalman Filter to predict motion.